# Sony Vegas Pro 17 - Speeding Up Video Slow Render

Tags: vegas-pro, sony

I shortened a 1h clip into 1min by speeding up the video 4x, saving it as .veg, and repeating until I was at 1min. When I try to render it as an mp4 it takes over 6h for 1 minute clip...

I render at 1080x1920 (for tiktok), 60fps, max bps 40mb, average bps 20mb, no audio, video rendering quality: best.

GPU: NVIDIA GeForxe GTX 1070

RAM: 16GB

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz, 4001 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)

Any Idea why the rendering might be taking so long and how could I shorten it? In the bottom right of sony vegas there is a time of around 1h which is the main clip. I am wondering if vegas is trying render all of the clip for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I believe Vegas will go through the entire hour of footage even if the end result is 1 minute. It is only possible to speed up by 12x each time ([Is it possible to speed up footage by more than 4x in Sony Vegas Movie Studio?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15187/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-footage-by-more-than-4x-in-sony-vegas-movie-studio), using 4x playback rate and 300% velocity) so it's not efficient for greater speedup like 60x.

What I do for my timelapses is use ffmpeg.  https://superuser.com/questions/1261678/how-do-i-speed-up-a-video-by-60x-in-ffmpeg